# Gulp root shows blank page

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp

I had angular JS web framework website, the source codes use gulp to run the server. The app folder is what I want to run. Every time I visit the website, I need to type "/app" at the end of my URL.

> https://www.myweb.com/app

I had used root attribute on connect.server function in Gulp. www.myweb.com/app no longer works for me and www.myweb.com shows blank page without error.

```
gulp.task('localhost', function() {
  connect.server({
      root: '/app',
      port: 4567,
      livereload: true
  });
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(['./app/*.html'], ['html']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['localhost', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can point the root of your application to the web server simply by specifying the directory name as a string. The web server is not able to find the location specified because of the `/`, so you could try passing just `root: 'app'`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems. First, the root path has to do with your file system, it's the directory your app is being served out of, not your URL. Second, having `/` at the beginning of your path makes it absolute, so it's trying to serve from a folder that doesn't exist at your system's root.

To make it serve such that your `app` directory is part of the path, change your root to `.` to make the current directory the gulp task starts in act as the root.